# got "Invalid protocol" with Proxy in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, proxy

I'm trying to connect via proxy in nodeJs, but I don't have any result or error.
I'm using `mikeal/request`.

I've tested proxy in the command line and it works properly:

```
$ http_proxy=localhost:9060 wget http://wtfismyip.com/json
$ cat json
```

returns

```
{
   "YourFuckingIPAddress" : "62.236.108.73",
   "YourFuckingLocation" : "Finland",
   "YourFuckingHostname" : "effi.org",
   "YourFuckingISP" : "TDC Oy Finland"
}
```

As expected. But my request in nodeJs:

```
router.route('/proxy-ip')
    .get(function (req, res) {

        var request_options = {
            url: 'http://wtfismyip.com/json',
            proxy: {
                host: "http://localhost",
                port: 9060
            }
        };

        console.log({request:request_options});

        request.get(request_options,
            function (error, response, json) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    res.send(json);
                } else {
                    console.log({'request': request, 'response': response, 'error': error, 'json': json});
                    res.send({'response': response, 'error': error, 'json': json});
                }
            }
        );

    });
```

log invalid protocol error:

```
  error: [Error: Invalid protocol: http]
```

Does anyone know how to fix it? Do anyone have working example with proxy in mikeal/request & nodejs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it!

I've replaced proxy object with string & it works:

```
            proxy: 'http://localhost:9060',
```